# How to check which database is being used in a Django project

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I want to use a queryset method that is only available in postgresql, if postgresql is being used.

How can I check the database from settings.DATABASES?

Assuming this structure:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # could be: 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'
```

My python skills are too weak to traverse that structure of dictionaries =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2':
   # happy coding
```

Answer (score 20):

This gives you the name of database backend configured as `default` in `settings.DATABASES`:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> print(connection.vendor)
'sqlite'
```

In case you have multiple databases configured:

```
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> print(connections['default'].vendor)
'mysql'
>>> print(connections['reporting'].vendor)
'postgresql'
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on the [answer posted by Ozgur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815824/4990392), in django shell, you need to have parentheses on the call to print:

```
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> print (connections['default'].vendor)
'mysql'
>>> print (connections['reporting'].vendor)
'postgresql'
```